# Mock Setup method throws an exception when there is a params parameter

Tags: c#, .net, mocking

I have a web service interface:

```
TOut Post<TIn, TOut>(TIn request, string baseAddress, string endpoint, int timeout = -1,params HttpStatusCode[] skipedCodeSuccessAuth );
```

Here I have defined two object types for TIn, TOut:

**UpdateTransactionRequest, UpdateTransactionResponse**

And I want to mock this, so that it returns whatever was passed in - something will be returned like:

```
  private void ServiceInvokerStub()
    {
        _mockServiceInvoker.Setup(x =>
                x.Post<UpdateTransactionRequest, UpdateTransactionResponse>(It.IsAny<UpdateTransactionRequest>(),
                    It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>(),It.IsAny<HttpStatusCode[]>()))
            .Returns((UpdateTransactionResponse a) => _updateTransactionResponse);
    }
```

However I got an exception as following, is there some good ideas about this issue?

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Moq.dll
> but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Invalid callback. Setup on method with 5
> parameter(s) cannot invoke callback with different number of
> parameters (1).

Comment: I think you mean `.Returns(_updateTransactionResponse);`